# Python test runs forever in Visual Studio

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create tests for my python module, but I am having all kind of issues.

**My tests never end, they seem to run forever.**

To discard an issue with the configuration of my solution, I created a new empty solution, with only a Python Application project and added a unit test. The default unit test never ends either!

I created a unit test directly under the test project:

- PythonTestApplication1

  - my_class.py

Its content is:

```
import unittest

class Test_my_class(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_A(self):
        self.fail("Not implemented")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I am new to Python, so I don't know if I am doing any obvious mistakes, regarding naming convention, spacing or anything else that could be causing this issue.

What could be causing my tests run forever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 and the issue got solved.**

However, I think the issue is already solved in Update 1.

From my research It may be related to [the issue posted here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/668). But I couldn't install Windows 10 to verify it.

I was also having issues discovering the tests. To address that:

- Select the Test x86 settings (Test => Test Settings => Default Processor Architecture => x86
- Test names should start with **test_**